# Manually updating portfolio value in GnuCash

Tags: stocks, gnucash

I have left Quicken version 8 to start using GnuCash.

One of Quicken's great assets is the capacity to record and/or display stock prices for any historical date, provided the history has been entered. I want to manually enter stock prices for, say, yesterday, to start the process, but I can't find how to either enter of display. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Personal Finance & Money! You seem to have ended up with two accounts, please see https://money.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for help with merging them.

Answer (score 2):

To enter stock prices go to `Tools -> Price Database` (`Price Editor` in older versions) and click `Add`. Select the security and enter the date and price. Use `Last` as the price type. If you haven't added the security yet you'll have to do [that first](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Stocks/add_stock).

To view stock prices over time go to `Reports -> Assets & Liabilities -> Price Scatterplot` and set the `Price of Commodity` to the security you want to view and set `Price Source` to `Price Database`.